# Zoom chart in mouse focus

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a custom chart which I scale using the following code:

```
final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;
        treePane.setOnScroll(new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ScrollEvent event)
            {
                event.consume();

                if (event.getDeltaY() == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                double scaleFactor = (event.getDeltaY() > 0) ? SCALE_DELTA : 1 / SCALE_DELTA;

                treePane.setScaleX(treePane.getScaleX() * scaleFactor);
                treePane.setScaleY(treePane.getScaleY() * scaleFactor);
            }
        });
```

I noticed that when I scroll the chart with mouse wheel I cannot zoom the chart where my mouse points. Instead of this the chart is zoomed to left or right for example.

I would like when I zoom with the mouse wheel to scale the chart where my cursor points. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with javafx, but I will try to answer anyway. From my experience with Win32Api/GDI and XNA you should definitely be able to read mouse coordinates. Anything you display is displayed at coordinates x,y. When you want to scale and zoom to the cursor's location, you will redraw with this in mind: (assume zoom factor = z, mouseX and mouseY the mouse coordinates X and Y the new coordinates)
your cursor will have to point at the same pixel, so if the image is z times bigger now, so will the mouse coordinates be, relative to the source of the picture. To these coordinates, essentially the distance from the top and left of the image, you have to add the coordinates of the source itself, which should remain unchanged relative to the window's top-left corner. This eventually means that mouseX - X = (mouseX - x)*z, which means X = mouseX - (mouseX - x)*z
Same goes for the Y coordinate. In theory this should work perfectly, i have not tried it with code but it seems right on paper. You will notice X and Y seem to be getting smaller, essentially they might even turn out negative since by scaling and keeping the mouse on the same pixel, you push/stretch the top-left corner further up and left, possibly out of the screen.
You will probably work with the scrollbars though, same philosophy on their displacement.
Play around with the variables a bit to make them fit the drawing mode, I do not know if the libraries you are working with start from the screen's (0,0), or the window's, or the working areas, so you will have to adapt it to the rest of the code, but this is the math/geometry behind it.